# Некоторые npm плагины невозможно использовать. Сборка которая работала раньше перестала работать

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, webpack, npm

У меня была сборка на Gulp. Там всё работало хорошо до недавнего времени. После того как я переустановил Windows 10 и теперь поставил 32bit (ПК плохо работал в 64bit) у меня стало выдавать ошибку при `npm run build`. При попытке build-а консоль находил ошибку в плагине `gulp-imagemin` и писал что `_function is not a function` (запомните это, я еще к этому вернусь).

[image: первая фотография]

Я даже пробовал написать `.pipe(imagemin())` - без настроек в скобках (свойства не обязательны), но ошибка всё ровно не исчезала. В сборке было еще очень много плагинов, но они все работали отлично.
После этого я решил создать свою для вёрстки на новом сборщике Vite. Я инициализировал проект и при попытке установки пакета для Pug вне выдало ошибку: я написал в консоль команду `npm i vite-plugin-pug -D`, и мне выдало ошибку.

[image: вторая фотография]

В консоле написано `Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps`. И я сделал так: установил пакет командой `npm i --force vite-plugin-pug -D` или `npm i --legacy-peer-deps vite-plugin-pug -D`. Оба варианата работают и пакет устанавливается. Я написал настройки плагина как указано в офф. странице плагина.

[image: третья фотография]

Но при запуске `npm run dev` мне выдавало ошибку.

[image: четвёртая фотография]

Консоль пишет что `pugPlugin is not a function`. То же самое что и писало в сборке Gulp при попытке запуска плагина `gulp-imagemin`. Опять же этот сборщик Vite отлично устанавливает другие плагины, и запускает тоже.
Я решил в своём js файле написать `import pugPlugin from "vite-plugin-pug"` и `console.log(pugPlugin);`. Но уже только при импорте мне выдавало ошибку.

[image: пятая фотография]

Я не знаю в чём проблема возможно это из за того что у меня 32bit, проблема появилась сразу после установки 32bit. До этого всё работало хорошо. Может кто то в курсе как решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

Используйте данные туториал по сборке:

https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в вопросе нет ничего что касалось бы сборки electron-приложения